# How to create a thread pool in iOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I want to be able to perform multiple background network operations in my app, but no more than N operations at any given time. Is there an  existing mechanism in iOS to create a thread pool of a specified size, and get one of the threads from it whenever I need to do something in the background? A GCD-based solution would be ideal, but I'm curious to hear about all the options.

Comment: Have a look at NSOperation and NSOperationQueue you can specify dependency between operations and also max number of concurrent operation in the queue. It uses GCD and you don't have to specify threads or anything. Just create a queue and add an operation to it.

Comment: There's an excellent series of articles here under "Concurrent Programming" ( [objc.io](http://www.objc.io/) ) on this topic, very useful, covers high level to low level approaches.

Comment: There is `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:url queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){}]` you can use together with an `NSOperationQueue`.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel.  Use the powerful tools that Apple provides.  GCD and NSOperationQueue do exactly what you want.  Definitely check out the objc.io article that Alfie mentioned too.

Comment: BTW, classes like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) make it very easy to create network operations that you can add to your `NSOperationQueue`. It gets you out of the weeds of `NSURLConnection` programming, but you can enjoy the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of `NSOperationQueue`, which achieves what you're looking for.